# Does Allah have a house?

Tags: hadith-interpretation

As per hadith of Bukhari it is mentioned prophet will enter Allah's house on the day of judgement. Does Allah have a house?

> Qatada said: I heard Anas saying that), the Prophet (ﷺ) said, "I will go out and take them out of Hell (Fire) and let them enter Paradise, and then I will return and ask my Lord for permission to enter **His House** and I will be permitted.
>
> Narrated in [Saheeh Bukhari 7440](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/66)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the hadith you quoted, the word "house" is a reference to *Jannah* and associated places of intercession, not to a physical house for Allah.

In [Fat'h Al-Bari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fath_al-Bari) (Arabic: فتح الباري شرح صحيح البخاري) by [Ibn Hajar al-Asqalani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Hajar_al-Asqalani) (Arabic: أحمد بن علي بن حجر العسقلاني), the [commentary](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=13609&bk_no=52&flag=1) on this hadith explains this phrase:

> وقوله « فأستأذن على ربي في داره فيؤذن لي عليه » قال الخطابي هذا يوهم المكان والله منزه عن ذلك، وإنما معناه في داره الذي اتخذها لأوليائه وهي الجنة وهي دار السلام، وأضيفت إليه إضافة تشريف مثل بيت الله وحرم الله
>
> <sub>*— NOTE: My own translation, so treat with care:*</sub>
>
> And his saying [in [Sahih al-Bukhari » Book of Oneness » Hadith 7440](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/66)]: "and I will ask my Lord's permission to enter His House and then I will be permitted", Al-Khattabi said this may insinuate a place, and Allah is exalted from that. Rather, this means a house that Allah has ordained for his guardians, namely *Jannah*, which is the house of peace. The attribution to Allah is a form of honoring the place, as in the case of calling [*Al-Ka'aba*] the house of Allah, or the sanctity of Allah.

This is a common phrase in the Arabic language — as well as other languages — to elevate the stance of a place. Calling *Al-Ka'aba* the House of Allah does not refer to it as a physical lodging anymore than Christians calling a church the House of God. This is also demonstrated in multiple verses in the Qur'an:

> وَاللَّهُ يَدْعُو إِلَىٰ دَارِ السَّلَامِ وَيَهْدِي مَن يَشَاءُ إِلَىٰ صِرَاطٍ مُّسْتَقِيمٍ
>
> And Allah invites to the Home of Peace and guides whom He wills to a straight path
>
> <sub>— [Qur'an 10:25](https://quran.com/10/25/)</sub>

Similarly, [Al-An'am 6:127](https://quran.com/6/127/) and [Fussilat 41:28](https://quran.com/41/28) use the word house in a similar fashion. [Ibn Al-Qayyim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Qayyim_al-Jawziyya) and ['Abdul-Haq Al-Eshbeeli](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%82_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%B4%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%84%D9%8A) said that the reference in this hadith is to the places of *shafa'ah* (intercession) — Refer to *Ijtima' Al-Juyush Al-Islamiyyah* (Arabic: [اجتماع الجيوش الإسلامية](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=24&bk_no=116&flag=1)
) and *Ma'arij Al- Qubool* (Arabic: [معارج القبول بشرح سلم الوصول إلى علم الأصول](http://froj.islamweb.org/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=112&ID=&idfrom=1&idto=286&bookid=112&startno=48)
)

Having said that, from a hadith perspective, this particular phrase of "and I will ask my Lord's permission to enter His House" was narrated only through the chain of Hammam Ibn Yahya (Arabic: [همام بن يحيى](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1207&bk_no=60&flag=1)) as per Ibn Hajar in the commentary linked above. In Sahih Al-Bukhari, this hadith was also narrated through three different chains (Hisham through Qatada in [Sahih al-Bukhari » Book of Oneness » Hadith 7410](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/39) and [Sahih al-Bukhari » Prophetic Commentary on the Qur'an » Hadith 4476](https://sunnah.com/urn/178030), Abu-'Uwana through Qatada in  [Sahih al-Bukhari » Book of To make the Heart Tender » Hadith 6565](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/154), and through Ma'bad bin Hilal Al-'Anzi in [Sahih al-Bukhari » Book of Oneness » Hadith 7510](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/135)) that do not have the phrase "and I will ask my Lord's permission to enter His House".

In other books of hadith ([Sahih Muslim » The Book of Faith » Hadith 193 a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:193a), [Sunan Ibn Majah » Zuhd » Hadith 4454](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:4312), and [Jami' at-Tirmidhi » Chapters on Tafsir » Hadith 3441](https://sunnah.com/urn/741670), among others), said phrase is also missing from the verse of the hadith.

Comment: Thanks, may Allah reward you for your efforts,Is fath ul bari available in English?

Comment: There are some volumes of Fat'h Al-Bari in English (see [here](http://islam786books.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=36_38&products_id=4580)), but I have not come across a complete translation.